# Write permissions of www-data user and public key issue

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git, ssh-keys, user-permissions

I am using Ubuntu and I am having the following problem.

I am using a PHP function called exec to get the latest git changes from my remote repo.
E.g.: `exec("git pull");`.

The file is placed in /var/www. When accessing from shell (user 'myapp') works fine. When done from browser, doesn't seem to work correctly.

However, this doesn't seem to work.
There could be 2 problems causing this (probably both):
1) the www-data user doesn't have sufficient permissions
2) git can't connect to my bitbucket repo because I don't have the public key for the www-data user so I can add that to BitBucket to allow access from this server

Is there anyone that can help with this permissions problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing SuPHP, so the php script runs under the user, and not under www-data.